# how to implement filter for multiple tags in single text field?

Tags: views

I am new to drupal and I got one site to modify which is developed in drupal 6.

I am using jQuery tags input plugin (http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/) for input field "state" and this state field accepts multiple states in the form of tag.

In my site I have used Views module for displaying job list in which filters are used and I want to use state field for filtering jobs.

When I enter multiple states the job should get filtered according to states.
What should I do for implementing this filter?

Here is my UI [image]

Comment: What have you tried so far, what didn't work, etc.? Please be sure to include descriptions of all your research efforts in the question, otherwise this is essentially _"I want someone to code a widget for me"_ which is not a reasonable request

Comment: Actually I got this site for modification and before I modifying this site there was sate field which was accepting only single state field and that time filters were working but I just modified this field and made it as multi-state field.

Comment: Ah ok so it's working now? If so and you have enough to say about it please be sure to add the solution in as an answer :)

Comment: I have not completed it.sir I am not getting the the idea to do it.please help..I am trying it from one week..Actually I am very new for drupal

Comment: Sorry but in my opinion this is too broad a question to ask here. It's also a requirement that you show your research effort as I mentioned, and asking for a full tutorial to do something is not appropriate for a Stack Exchange site. However I'm not sure if this is something that would be easily doable with a contrib module or something so I won't close the question. But I promise that you'll get a much better response from the community here if you show the effort you've put in to solve the problem yourself, regardless of how far towards a solution that effort got you